# Wordpress: enqueue a script only if a widget is used

Tags: wordpress, widget

There is a way to enqueue a script only if a widget is used (pay attention, not if is active, but if it is present inside a sidebar in a page/post)? Or even better: there is a way to enqueue a script only if a particular string appears inside a sidebar?

Comment: Answer to this question has been posted  [here][1] 


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48337/how-to-enqueue-script-if-widget-is-displayed-on-page/#95441

Answer (score 9):

Just enqueue the script or stylesheet in the widget function. This is the easiest and best approach.

```
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        // outputs the content of the widget

        // Enqueue a script needed for
        // the Widget's output
        wp_enqueue_script( 'your_script', $path, $deps );

        // Rest of widget output goes here...
    }
```

Comment: This answer seems superior to me than the one (currently the top answer) that uses wp_print_styles. The WP codex currently includes a warning that wp_print_styles is dangerous to use after v3.3. The wp_print_styles option also causes the link to the script to appear in the middle of the html content, possibly causing blocking problems.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually tested, this but one possible solution would be to enqueue your script to the footer.

#### If widget is used

When you build the widget, you can add some code to the `widget()` function of your widget's class (the function at actually outputs the widget to the screen).  You could call `wp_enqueue_script()` from here, [just make sure you flag it to be used in the footer](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).

This will print your script where `wp_footer()` is called rather than where `wp_head()` is called, but only if the widget is invoked on the page.

#### If a string appears in the sidebar

Basically, just filter the sidebar for your string.  If the string is present, enqueue your script to the footer the same way you would with a widget.

---

#### (Update) Alternatives

There are two other things you can do.  First, you can use jQuery to namespace your functionality.  Basically, give your widget a unique ID (say "my-unique-id"), then download your script asynchrounously:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if( jQuery('#my-unique-id').length > 0 ) {

        jQuery.getScript( [your-script-url] );

    }
}
```

This code will check to see if your widget ID is on the page ... if so, it downloads your script from the server, if not, it does nothing.  You can also build this code in PHP to include either a relative or absolute reference to your script file.  It's up to you.

Alternatively, you could just include your script in an inline `<script>` block in your widget's code.  This will work the way you want it to, but it breaks all kinds of standard coding practices.  Code should typically be in the `<header>` or placed directly before the closing `</body>` tag ... but you can really put it anywhere you want.

Comment: Thanks, but if you add wp_enqueue_script() to the widget() function the script is ignored. You must add the enqueue to the class, but in this case the script is enqueued even if the widget is not present on the page.
I don't know how your second tip could work, sorry.

Comment: @pixedelic Which part are you referring to as "doesn't seem a good WordPress practice?"

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right. I meant: if you call the script with a jQuery function you can't check if the script is already present in the page. I need to use a Wordpress function.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I considered 'wp_footer' hook because this hook is executed at footer,and is probably the best way to add scripts only where the widget is used.

```
class Your_Widget extends WP_Widget{

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {

         add_action('wp_footer',array($this,'front_end_scripts'));

    }

    function front_end_scripts(){
       ?><script type="text/javascript">
          console.log('this works!');
        /*
          Or if you need external scripts then you may use 
          $.getScript([your-script-url] );
        */
        </script> <?php
    }



}
```

Comment: Why on earth a downvote? If people can't suggest a different approach then let's kill Stack altogether...